# Binary Search Tree operations

Tags: python, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement Binary Search Tree operations in python. As of now, I have written some code to add nodes to this search tree (sorted).
Here's what I've in my code:

```
class TreeNode:

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.lLink = None
        self.rLink = None

class BinaryTree:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def AddNode(self, data):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = TreeNode(data)
        else:
            if data < self.root.data:
                if self.root.lLink is None:
                    self.root.lLink = TreeNode(data)
                else:
                    AddNode(self.root.lLink, data)
            else:
                if self.root.rLink is None:
                    self.root.rLink = TreeNode(data)
                else:
                    AddNode(self.root.rLink, data)

    def InOrder(self, head):
        if self.root.lLink is not None:
            InOrder(self.root.lLink)
        print self.root.data,
        if self.root.rLink is not None:
            InOrder(self.root.rLink)

    myTree = BinaryTree()
    myTree.AddNode(15)
    myTree.AddNode(18)
    myTree.AddNode(14)
```

How do I test if my `AddNode()` method is correct? I know the algorithm but just to be sure.
What I was thinking of is to create an InOrder() method and try to print elements through this InOrder traversal. As a result, my data added to the tree should be displayed in sorted order. If it is displayed in sorted order, I'll be sure that both my AddNode() and InOrder() methods are correct.

Comment: Do you wan't InOrder() to print the data from the far left to the far right? Why does InOrder() take a head parameter...what's that for?

Comment: That is exactly how you should be testing the insert function. so, dont you have your answer? what more do you want to know?

Comment: Oh wait, the InOrder doesn't work at all. Posting a change.

Answer (score 1):

Your `BinaryTree` class is faulty, changing the order of insertions to

```
myTree.AddNode(14)
myTree.AddNode(18)
myTree.AddNode(15)
```

raises an error - `NameError: global name 'AddNode' is not defined`.

This is because in the lines, `AddNode(self.root.rLink, data)` and `AddNode(self.root.lLink, data)` you seem to be calling the `AddNode` function on instances of `TreeNode` which is not possible. I fixed up some of the errors in your code and it should work great now.

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.lLink = None
        self.rLink = None

class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def AddNode(self, data):
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = TreeNode(data)
        else:
            self.AddHelper(data, self.root)

    def AddHelper(self, data, startingPoint):
        if data < startingPoint.data:
            if startingPoint.lLink is None:
                startingPoint.lLink = TreeNode(data)
            else:
                self.AddHelper(data, startingPoint.lLink)
        else:
            if startingPoint.rLink is None:
                startingPoint.rLink = TreeNode(data)
            else:
                self.AddHelper(data, startingPoint.rLink)

    def InOrder(self):
        self.InOrderHelper(self.root)

    def InOrderHelper(self, startingPoint):
        if startingPoint is None:
            return
        self.InOrderHelper(startingPoint.lLink)
        print startingPoint.data,
        self.InOrderHelper(startingPoint.rLink)
```

Output Test :

```
>>> myTree = BinaryTree()
>>> myTree.AddNode(14)
>>> myTree.AddNode(18)
>>> myTree.AddNode(15)
>>> myTree.InOrder()
14 15 18
```

Comment: I didnt bother to check the insert function. :D

Comment: That's what OP was going for. He wanted to check it's correctness. I just went in and fixed all the errors, if you catch any more, let me know. :)

Answer (score -1):

Inserting can be a little tricky, especially because the function is a part of the tree itself. So, you call the insert function on the tree, but specifying a starting point. This defaults to root, so you can leave the argument when you call the function.

Also, I think you are a little unclear about how `self` works in a function. You cannot pass it as an argument to the function, which is what it seems you have done.

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.rLink = None
        self.lLink = None

class BinaryTree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def AddNode(self, data, node=None):
        if not node :
            node = self.root
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = TreeNode(data)
        else:
            if data < node.data:
                if node.lLink is None:
                    node.lLink = TreeNode(data)
                else:
                    self.AddNode(data, self.root.lLink)
            else:
                if node.rLink is None:
                    node.rLink = TreeNode(data)
                else:
                    self.AddNode(data, self.root.rLink)

    def InOrder(self, head):
        if head.lLink is not None:
            self.InOrder(head.lLink)
        print head.data,
        if head.rLink is not None:
            self.InOrder(head.rLink)

myTree = BinaryTree()
myTree.AddNode(14)
myTree.AddNode(15)
myTree.AddNode(18)
myTree.InOrder(myTree.root)
```

Testing the insert function with an in-order traversal is the best approach.

This should work. You are not going down the tree if you use `self.root.lLink` every time.
Optionally, you could write one more line of code to check if the output is indeed in ascending order.